# numerator and denominator not aligned

Tags: math-mode

this is my first question here, so it must be very basic. I've written the following line (in an latex snippet in org-mode, don't know if it matters):

```
\[
\frac {k(n^2 - \[\sum n_{i}^2\])}{n^2(k-1)}
\]
```

But it appears that numerator and denumerator are not aligned at all, here a screenshot:
[image]

n^2(k-1) should be the denominator.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Take out the `\[` and `\]` in the middle of the equation.

Comment: This is a single formula, so it needs a single `\[` for opening and a single `\]` for closing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference: while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest the math environment delimiters `\[` and `\]` so you should have written

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac {k(n^2 - \sum n_{i}^2)}{n^2(k-1)}
\]
\end{document}
```